# Skype issues with key repeat

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, skype, input

The problem I have is uncontrollable key repeat within Skype, which then makes the pc unusable for that session. This does not happen unless I use Skype for Linux, but when it starts I cannot type without multiple key repetitions.  And this is then the case for other programs I try to use in that session.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS running on a Lenovo Thinkpad L460 (dual boot with Windows 10).

This problem has been happening for about 6 months, maybe more, only with Skype for Linux.   I think it started after an update of Skype.

Comment: yes, happening with me as well but only after I am on 1:1 call. everything works fine if I am on group call.